# how to fetch float value which is stored in sqlite database?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

```
-(NSMutableArray *)getStudentsInfo
{
    NSMutableArray *studentsList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    sqlite3_stmt* getStatement;

    const char* sql = "select * from Person";

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &getStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error: failed to prepare statement with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }
    else{

        while (sqlite3_step(getStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            Person* pObj = [[Person alloc]init];

            pObj.pNumber = sqlite3_column_int(getStatement,0);

            pObj.pName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(getStatement, 1)];


            NSLog(@"Student Name is %@",pObj.pName);

            pObj.pRoundTime = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(getStatement, 2)];


            NSLog(@"Student Class is %@",pObj.pRoundTime);

            pObj.pRoundCount = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(getStatement, 3)];


            NSLog(@"Student Section is %@",pObj.pRoundCount);

            pObj.pRestTime = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(getStatement, 4)];


            NSLog(@"Student Section is %@",pObj.pRestTime);

             pObj.pAlertTime = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(getStatement, 5)];



             NSLog(@"Student Section is %@",pObj.pAlertTime);

             pObj.pPreparationTime = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(getStatement, 6)];



            NSLog(@"Student Section is %@",pObj.pPreparationTime);






            [studentsList addObject:pObj];
        }
        printf("Successfully retrieved data from database");

    }
    sqlite3_finalize(getStatement);

    return studentsList;

}
```

I have a problem here that I have stored all these fields are stored as float values in a sqlite database except first two fields. But when I want to fetch all these records using select query I won't get and shown the records and it is shown error below:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSString stringWithUTF8String:]: NULL cString'

Answer (score 2):

Replace `sqlite3_column_text` with `sqlite3_column_double` to fetch float value in above code.

```
NSNumber *floatValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(float)sqlite3_column_double(statement, column)];
```

Above is the way you can apply to get float value.

Comment: eventhough i used sqlite3_column_double its showing error like double cannot be point with others. can you please write the statement properly

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
sqlite3_column_double(statement, column)
```

Instead of:

```
sqlite3_column_text(statement, column)
```

If integer:

```
sqlite3_column_int(statement, column)
```

Answer (score 1):

even though i used double to fetch float values its shown error
can any one tell me how write the proper line for these below line

```
pObj.pRoundTime = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(getStatement, 2)];
```

Comment: here pRoundTime string object